# Ordering using PHP but some entries can have the same value

Tags: php

I'm working on a horse rating system and I need to assign values to each horse based on the value of another (already filled) field (all this is stored in a MySQL db).

Consider the following simplified example:-

A four horse race where the odds for each horse are as follows:-

Horse A - 2/1
Horse B - 3/1
Horse C - 3/1
Horse D - 5/1

As Horse A has the lowest price, I want to give it a value of 1.

However, Horse B and C have the same price and so I want to give them both 2.

Horse D has the next highest price and so I want to give it the value of 3.

When I first started to do this, I thought it would be easy but it has now reached the stage where the loops are driving me loopy. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

In view of the response I received below from Daan then I should also add that my problem is further compounded by the fact that my table has several subsets (i.e. it contains more than one race on any given day and they need to be ranked individually).

My table is currently:-

racedate | racetime | racecourse | horsename | forecast | forecast_rate | id

The racedate for the purposes of this will always be the same. The racetime and racecourse together identify the race in question.

forecast is the price given to each horse (this has already been entered at this stage) and this is what needs to have the shared ranking done on it to be stored in forecast_rate.

id is just the unique index for each entry in the table.

This is what I have now got to (and it doesn't work... surprise...)

```
    $testdude=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT racecourse,racetime FROM picking") or die(mysql_error());

while($rih=mysql_fetch_array($testdude)){
$testdude1=mysql_query("SELECT s1.forecast, s1.horsename, COUNT(DISTINCT s2.forecast) AS rank FROM picking s1 JOIN picking s2 ON (s1.forecast <= s2.forecast) GROUP BY s1.horsename;");
while($rih1=mysql_fetch_array($testdude1)){
mysql_query("UPDATE picking SET forecast_rate='$testdude1[rank]' where horsename='$testdude1[horsename]'") or die(mysql_error());
}
}
```

Comment: I tried doing it on the PHP side at first but the mysql side seems to be the way to go. Unfortunately, my PHP knowledge is about ten ... no one hundred times better than my mysql so if I couldn't get it working using PHP then my mysql efforts would only be embarrassing! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is called shared ranking and it's easiest to do this in MySQL. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-ranking-without-self-join) and see whether you can get that to work. If not, please provide more details about your table lay-out, and I'll get you a tailored example :)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply and apologies for taking two days to get around to thanking you! That does look like what I need to do and I'll have a read through. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if there are any problems :) (I'd appreciate an upvote if this was helpful to you!)

Comment: I did try Daan but I need 15 rep to upvote. Any suggestions on the code I have put above (which doesn't work!)?